# bluimp library. Getting a mysql error

Tags: php

Bluimp and PHP

Iam using the bluimp upload library to upload my CSV files which have huge data  and after upload the data will be inserted into the database. Iam trying to upload like 10 files at a time. And this gives me a error.

xampp is killed and getting the error
"mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): An operation on a socket could not be performed because  the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full."

I observed that bluimp is trying to upload 6 files at a time. How to make it process 1 file at a time.

Comment: Have you tried `maxNumberOfFiles: 1` ?

Comment: I have tried that but this does not allow me to upload multiple files. I want to upload multiple files but the processing should be one at a tme